# Data binding in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Hy . I am new in windows phone app development. i want to know how to bind text box data with list box / rich text block which is on next page.
I want to bind multiple text box with a single list box / rich text block. can any one help to give sample code or give tutorial. I have visited channel 9 but i did not understand.
Thanks

Comment: Could you post some code so we can understand precisely what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a XAML control value to another XAML control value in the same page, you can use {Binding ElementName=xxx} where xxx is your first control you want to bind to.
If you want to bind a control to a data value : use [MVVM pattern like explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153(v=vs.105).aspx)